# Integrable functions vanish at infinity a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is integrable with repsect to Lebesgue measure. Prove that for almost every $x\in[0,1]$ the sequence $\{f(x+n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ tends to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Let $g_n(x)=f(x+n)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then above claim is equivalent to show that $g_n\rightarrow0$ pointwise on $[0,1]$ almost every. I'm puzzled by this problem. Could someone give useful hints or solution?

Comment: Have you thought about contradiction? Suppose there's a set of positive measure on which $|g_n|>\epsilon$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Caution: if $g_n(x)$ doesn't converge to $0$ there is some $\epsilon > 0$ and some subsequence on which $|g_n(x)| > \epsilon$.  But it might be a different subsequence for each $x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Let $A=\{x\in[0,1]: \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|g_n(x)|>0\}$. The contradiction is $m(A)>0$. But we cannot get your assumption.

Comment: Yup. Fair enough. I shouldn't meddle in real analysis without more thought :P I actually intended my hint not as a precise statement but as a heuristic. But it was misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 |f(x+n)|\; dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(x+n)|\; dx $$

Comment: It's perfect! Thx.